# Using Flutter dependency form a private Bitbucket repo

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When trying to use a private repo as a dependency in a Flutter project, I get this error when doing `flutter packages get` (from IntelliJ):

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
```

My `pubspec.yaml` looks like this

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  myrepo:
    git:
      url: git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myrepo.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for me was to run the following command:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I then got a question to enter my SSH passphrase

```
Enter passphrase for /Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

and after entering it I got the following confirmation:

```
Identity added: /Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

After this, running `flutter packages get` worked like a charm!